# DISTRIBUTE BY clause in HIVE

Tags: hive, hiveql, hadoop2

I am not able to understand what this `DISTRIBUTE BY` clause does in **Hive**. I know the definition that says, if we have `DISTRIBUTE BY (city)`, this would send each city in a different **reducer** but I am not getting the same. Let us consider the data as follows:

Say we have a table called *data* with columns *username* and *amount*:

```
+----------+--------+
| username | amount |
+----------+--------+
| user_1   | 25     |
+----------+--------+
| user_1   | 53     |
+----------+--------+
| user_1   | 28     |
+----------+--------+
| user_1   | 50     |
+----------+--------+
| user_2   | 20     |
+----------+--------+
| user_2   | 50     |
+----------+--------+
| user_2   | 10     |
+----------+--------+
| user_2   | 5      |
+----------+--------+
```

Now If I say -

```
SELECT username, SUM(amount) FROM data DISTRIBUTE BY (username)
```

Shouldn't this run 2 separate reducers? It is still running a single reducer and I don't know why. I thought this may have to do with **clustering into buckets** or **partitioning** but I tried everything, and it still runs a single reducer. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The only thing `DISTRIBUTE BY (city)` says is that records with the same `city` will go to the same reducer. Nothing else.

> Hive uses the columns in Distribute By to distribute the rows among
>   reducers. All rows with the same Distribute By columns will go to the
>   same reducer

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SortBy

---

A question by the OP:

> Then what is the point of this DISTRIBUTE BY ? There's no guarantee
>   that each (city) would go to a different reducer then why use it ?

---

For 2 reasons:

1. In the beginning of hive `DISTRIBUTE BY`, `SORT BY` and `CLUSTER BY` where used to process data in a way that today is being done automatically (e.g. analytic functions https://oren.lederman.name/?p=32)
2. You might want to stream you data through a script (Hive "Transform") and you want your script to process your data in certain groups and order. For that you can use `DISTRIBUTE BY` + `SORT BY` or `CLUSTER BY`. With `DISTRIBUTE BY` it is guaranteed that you'll have the whole group in the same reducer. With `SORT BY` that you'll get all the records of a group continuously.

Comment: As in if I say there are four cities A,B,C and D , A should go a different reducer , B to different and so on ?

Comment: No. All A would go to 1 reducer. All B will go to 1 reducer You have no guarantee that these are going to be different reducers.

Comment: All right so we can say at a time a reducer will contain only (1) kind of city ?

Comment: Also no. Every record that is being read by a mapper is being copied to one of the reducers, decided by Hash function(s) over the distribution value(s), in this case `city` and this take place only after the number of reducers is being decided.

Comment: Seriously I don't get it. Then what is the point of this DISTRIBUTE BY ?
There's no guarantee that each (city) would go to a different reducer then why use it ?

Comment: For 2 reasons **(1)** In the beginning of hive DISTRIBUTE BY, SORT BY and CLUSTER BY where used to process data in a way that today is being done automatically (e.g. analytic functions http://oren.lederman.name/?p=32)  **(2)** You might want to stream you data through a script (Hive "Transform") and you want your script to process your data in certain groups and order. For that you can use DISTRIBUTE BY + SORT BY or CLUSTER BY. With DISTRIBUTE BY it is guaranteed that you'll have the whole group in the same reducer. With SORT BY that you'll get all the records of a group continuously.

Comment: Finally got it. Thank you very much !

Comment: Hey @DavidדודוMarkovitz I used `DISTRIBUTE BY` clause as you said... But what if my tables don't have partitions? Then how can I make sure that my files goes into single reducer? I am trying to address the small files issue using `insert overwrite` of hive to merge them into bigger one.. For partitioned table `distribute by` seems to work fine but what when I don't have any partition columns?

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @Dudu's answer, the *Distribute By* only distributes the rows among the reducers which is determined from the input size.

The number of reducers to be used for a Hive job will be determined by this property `hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer` which is dependent on the input.

As of Hive 0.14, if the input is **< 256MB**, only one reducer (one reducer per 256MB of input) will be used unless the number of reducers is overridden by `hive.exec.reducers.max` or `mapred.reduce.tasks` properties.

Comment: So If I want a different reducer for say each (city) , I am supposed to know the number of DISTINCT cities right ?

Comment: No. It is clear that the number of the reducers must be greater or equal to the number of cities in order to have each city on a different reducer, but nothing guarantees it. It is a hash function and theoretically you can have 10 cities and 100 reducers and still all the cities will be on a single reducer.

Comment: Hiii @franklinsijo both `hive.exec.reducers.max` and `mapred.reduce.tasks` doesnt seem to work. I want to set the no. of reducers to 1, so that all files go into one reducer and get merged as a single one. Since, my table does not have partitions I am not able to use `DISTRIBUTE BY` clause to send files of single partition into one reducer. Do you anyway I can set no. of reducers to 1??